# some connection Problem with SqlServer 2008

Tags: ssms

A connection was successfully established with the server,but then an error occured during .the login process.(provider:Named Pipes Provider,error:0-No Process is on the other end of the Pipe.)

when my application starts i got this error

Answer (score 0):

Go to SQL Server Configuration Manager and make sure the TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled in SQL Server Network Configuration